# Rails - How to select the last date in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I select the last date in a table where the column name is Lars.

I have tried this:

```
<%= Reklamer.where(":dato => :dato, AND :name => :name", :date => Date.last, :name => "Lars")  %>
```

I have tried this:

```
<%= Reklamer.where(name: 'Lars').order('dato ASC').limit(1).select('dato').inspect %>
```

Output:`[#<Reklamer dato: "2011-02-15 23:53:28">]`

I need just a datetime format like: 2011-02-15 23:53:28

How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to order by the date and select a single record:

```
<%= Reklamer.where(name: 'Lars').order('dato DESC').first %>
```

You can accomplish this by limiting to a single record as well:

```
Reklamer.where(name: 'Lars').order('dato DESC').limit(1)
```

If you just want the last date from the last entry, you can do this:

```
Reklamer.where(name: 'Lars').last.dato
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not less efficient than using single sql query with `.find(:first, :conditions => [...], :order => ..., :limit => 1)`? Won't it have to fetch all 'reclaimers' from db first?  But +1 in any case.

Comment: No, the where and order and limit are all scoped, so the query is not executed until .first is called and .first is the equivalent of using LIMIT 1.

Comment: What if I just need to find the last date in the table? :)

Comment: Can I set name to nothing. Just need to find the last date in table

Comment: How do I transform the #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3c63120> to an date?

Comment: If you call limit(1) you'll need to call .first to get the first record, or .all to get the record in an array. You can't just call .dato or .to_i on a Relation.

Comment: Can you show my how to get a normal date like 2011-02-15 23:53:28 ? :)

Comment: Reklamer.where(name: 'Lars').order('dato ASC').first.dato forget the inspect and the limit clause in your example. This should give you a Time or DateTime object that you can reformat into any date/time format you want using strftime.